# This sql statement works only if a store_location value is a single word, and doesn't work for multiple words

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these SQL statements below for generating a pivot table.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
  'SUM(
  CASE WHEN store_location = "', store_location, '" THEN num_sales ELSE 0 END) 
  AS ', store_location)
)
INTO @sql
FROM product_sales;
 
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product_name, ', @sql, 
  ' FROM product_sales GROUP BY product_name');
SELECT @sql;
 
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

It works in the table below, in which store_location is a single word.

| product_name | store_location | num_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | North | 17 |
| Desk | West | 30 |
| Desk | North | 44 |
| Chair | South | 20 |
| Desk | East | 25 |
| Chair | East | 20 |
| Desk | South | 25 |
| Chair | West | 13 |

But does not work for the table below, in this case store_location has multiple words.

| product_name | store_location | num_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | North City | 17 |
| Desk | West City | 30 |
| Desk | North City | 44 |
| Chair | South City | 20 |
| Desk | East City | 25 |
| Chair | East City | 20 |
| Desk | South City | 25 |
| Chair | West City | 13 |

I have tried to use backticks around store_location in the SQL statement, but still, it does not work.

It gives this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'City,SUM(
  CASE WHEN store_location = "North City" THEN num_sales ELSE 0 END) ' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using backticks works for me:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
  'SUM(
  CASE WHEN store_location = "', store_location, '" THEN num_sales ELSE 0 END) 
  AS `', store_location, '`')
)
INTO @sql
FROM product_sales;
 
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product_name, ', @sql, 
  ' FROM product_sales GROUP BY product_name');
SELECT @sql;
 
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jcx19qaUF9FoNLNnzw6jNc/0).

Comment: Thank you very much,  I was putting backticks inside the single quotes. Now it works.